# Errors Accessing Ebay.com via HTMLUnit

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit

Im trying to access https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SellItem with selenium and using HTMLunit as the driver, but I am getting a lot of errors. I have tested my code using the firefox driver and everything is working perfectly.

This is how I have setup the driver: (I have tried different browser versions)

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

The output contains many errors such as:

```
Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript 
WARNING: CSS warning: 'https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&ru=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2F' [1:1687] Ignoring the whole rule.
```

However, I believe that the real issue is a javascript execution error. The console has also outputted this:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property "_l" of null to "function () {
    var js = this.createElement("script");
    if (dom) {
       this.domain = dom;
    }
    js.id = "js-iframe-async";
    js.src = rtmAsyncURL;
    this.body.appendChild(js);
}" (script in https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&ru=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2F from (10, 5429) to (15, 10)#13)
```

I am not quite sure how to tackle this problem, any help regarding accessing Ebay via HTMLunit would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24" indicates you are using an old version of HtmlUnit. Please try with the latest one. If you still find problems (yes, there are still man issues with javascript), please open an issue and i will try to help you.